# $.get() generated HTML are not recognized

Tags: jquery

In `main.php`, I have:

```
$('#GiveMeATextbox').click(function(){
  $.get('ReturnATextbox',{'jsample':'sample'}, function(d){$('#container').html(d); });
});

$('#IamReturnedTextbox').click(function(){
  alert("successful");
});
```

And my HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="button" id="GiveMeATextbox"></input>
</div>
```

and in ReturnATextbox.php

```
echo "<input type="text" id="IamReturnedTextbox"></input>"
```

My problem is that

```
$('#IamReturnedTextbox').click(function(){
  alert("successful");
});
```

won't work - it seems that the `Main.php` doesn't recognise the `$.get` generated HTML.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Alright! i believe the other people are missing the point.

if i am right you are already loading the content successfully.

the problem is you are trying to run a function on an element that doesnt exist until the $.get is fired.

two solutions.

```
//either a live call which will work on elements loaded into the dom after the initial page load
$('#IamReturnedTextbox').live("click",function(){ 
    alert("successful"); 
});

//or a callback on the $.get function
$.get("file here",function(){
    $('#IamReturnedTextbox').click(function(){ 
        alert("successful"); 
    });
)};
```

hope this helps!

Comment: +1 Yes this should work, because he's attaching click event to an element, that doesn't yet exists (maybe he's not aware of the asynchronous nature of Ajax calls - who knows).

Answer (score 0):

you're missing the .php extension inside the $.get call.

you should write like this:

```
$.get('ReturnATextbox.php',{'jsample':'sample'}, function(d){$('#container').html(d); }); });
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$('#GiveMeATextbox').click(function(){ $.get('ReturnATextbox.php',{jsample:'sample'}, function(d){$('#container').html(d); }); });
```

Hope it'll work ^^